# rdlc: Display percentage on pie chart

Tags: rdlc

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 reporting to generate a report which has a table and a pie chart. Both work just fine except that for the pie chart, I'm to put the % value on each pie chart slice.
1. Is this even possible?
2. If it is, how do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To put the % value on each pie chart slice do this (as shown [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239373%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)):

1. On the design surface, right-click on the pie and select Show Data Labels. The data labels should appear within each slice on the pie chart.
2. On the design surface, right-click on the labels and select Series Label Properties. The Series Label Properties dialog box appears.
3. Type #PERCENT for the Label data option.

Beware: If you use multiple data fields like this: [image] 
you need to move every field to first position and perform above steps as shown [here](http://www.morrenth.com/report-designer-rdlc-pie-chart-data-labels-for-multiple-data-fields.aspx) otherwise you end up with only one pie chart slice showing the percentage and the others are blank...

Comment: Perfect answer!